# Laravel: Array to string conversion Error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make search function and having problem. I have Array to string conversion error message.
Could you teach me right code please?

Here is this program usage

1.User select value then click [search] button (This is search.blade.php)

2.Search result will display at result.blade.php

my Laravel Framework is 6.18.8

**search.blade.php**

```
    <form action="{{ route('search') }}" class="form-image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="col-md-5">    
                <strong>TYPE</strong>    
                <select name="type" class="form-control">
                <option value="-" selected>-</option>
                <option value="j">j</option>
                <option value="w">w</option>
                </select>         
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <strong>wc</strong>
                <select name="wc" class="form-control">
                <option value="N0" selected>0</option>
                <option value="N1">1</option>
                <option value="N2">2</option>
                <option value="N3">3</option>    
                </select> 
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-5">
                <strong>FC</strong>
                <select name="fc" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected>0</option>                   
                <option value="f01">f01</option>
                <option value="f02">f02</option>
                <option value="f03">f03</option>    
                </select>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <strong>YC</strong>
                <select name="yc" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected>0</option>                   
                <option value="yc1">yc1</option>
                <option value="yc2">yc2</option>    
                </select>     
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <strong>SC</strong>
                <select name="sc" class="form-control">
                <option value="Z01" selected>Z01</option>                   
                <option value="Z02" selected>Z02</option>
                <option value="Z03" selected>Z03</option>
                </select>      
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">

            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>    
        </div>    
    </div>   
</form>
```

**result.blade.php**

```
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
<div class='list-group gallery'>
        @if($images->count())
            @foreach($images as $image)
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
            <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="/images/{{ $image->image }}">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/images/{{ $image->image }}" />
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <small class='text-muted'></small>
                </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
            </a> 
        </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div> <!-- list-group / end -->
```

**ImageGalleryController.php**

```
public function search()

{
    $images = ImageGallery::get();
    return view('search',compact('images'));
}

public function order(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->all();
    $images = ImageGallery::where(['type',$request->$data['type']],
        ['wc',$request->$data['type']],
        ['fc',$request->$data['fc']],
        ['yc',$request->$data['yc']],
        ['sc',$request->$data['sc']])->get();

    return view('result',compact('images'));
}
```

Web.php

```
// search section
Route::post('search', 'ImageGalleryController@order');
Route::get ('search', 'ImageGalleryController@search');
```

***UPDATE***

**Curent my controller**

```
public function search()

    {
        $images = ImageGallery::get();
        return view('search',compact('images'));
    }

    public function order(Request $request) {

        $data = $request->all();

        $images = ImageGallery::where([
            ['type', $data['type']],
            ['wc',$data['type']],
            ['fc',$data['fc']],
            ['yc',$data['yc']],
            ['sc',$data['sc']]
        ])->get();

         dd($images); 
        return view('search', compact('images'));

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

**search.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" class="form-image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="col-md-5">    
        <strong>TYPE</strong>    
        <select name="type" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="j">j</option>
            <option value="w">w</option>
        </select>         
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <strong>wc</strong>
        <select name="wc" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option> 
            <option value="N0">0</option>
            <option value="N1">1</option>
            <option value="N2">2</option>
            <option value="N3">3</option>    
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <strong>FC</strong>
        <select name="fc" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>                   
            <option value="f01">f01</option>
            <option value="f02">f02</option>
            <option value="f03">f03</option>    
        </select>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <strong>YC</strong>
        <select name="yc" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>                   
            <option value="yc1">yc1</option>
            <option value="yc2">yc2</option>    
        </select>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <strong>SC</strong>
        <select name="sc" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Z01">Z01</option>                   
            <option value="Z02">Z02</option>
            <option value="Z03">Z03</option>
        </select>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>    
    </div>   
</form>
```

**result.blade.php**

```
<div class='list-group gallery'>
    @if($images->count())
        @foreach($images as $image)
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
            <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="/images/{{ $image->image }}">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/images/{{ $image->image }}" />
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <small class='text-muted'></small>
                </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
            </a> 
        </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div> <!-- list-group / end -->
```

**ImageGalleryController.php**

```
public function search()
    {
        $images = \App\ImageGallery::get();

        return view('search', compact('images'));
    }

    public function order(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->all();

        $images = \App\ImageGallery::when($data['type'], function ($query, $type) {
            return $query->where('type', $type);
        })->
        when($data['fc'], function ($query, $fc) {
            return $query->orWhere('fc', $fc);
        })->
        when($data['yc'], function ($query, $yc) {
            return $query->orWhere('yc', $yc);
        })->
        when($data['wc'], function ($query, $wc) {
            return $query->orWhere('wc', $wc);
        })->
        when($data['sc'], function ($query, $sc) {
            return $query->orWhere('sc', $sc);
        })
        ->get();

        return view('result', compact('images'));
    }
```

**This is the database structure:**

[image]

This is the full working code on my local system.

**This is web.php file**

```
Route::get ('search', 'ImageGalleryController@search');
Route::post('search', 'ImageGalleryController@order')->name('search');
```

Comment: @greeniron check this solution.

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra Thank you very much! I'm checking right now ... now I got routing error . Could you show me web.php POST and GET code ?

Comment: @greeniron check the updated answer. It now contains your web.php file content.

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra Thank you very much!!! This is perfect! Amazing!!! I'm so happy! Thank you aganin! . May I ask one thing? It's my bad. I told wrong sql. Sorry. I would like to make sql like this  "select * from image_gallery where (type = ? or wc = ? or fc = ? or yc = ? or sc = ?)" . Could you teach me please ? This is last favor.

Comment: @greeniron pls check the updated answer. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!! Your help and code are Amazing and Perfect !!! Thank you very very much! you saved my life!!! I love you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add csrf token in your form.

@csrf

2. Change order function as:

   public function order(Request $request) {

   ```
   $data = $request->all();

   $images = ImageGallery::where([
       ['type', $data['type']],
       ['wc',$data['type']],
       ['fc',$data['fc']],
       ['yc',$data['yc']],
       ['sc',$data['sc']]
   ])->get();
   return view('result', compact('images'));
   ```

   }
3. Give name method to route:

Route::post('search', 'ImageGalleryController@order')->name('search');

Comment: @greeniron pls check the answer and let me know it work or not.

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra Thank you so much for answer and I'm sorry to late reply. Array to string conversion Error message is gone now. 
but I have another problem.I change my code as you taught me. and now I got this error 
"Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Call to a member function count() on string " so I tryed to check what is happing, I add 
->toSql(); var_dump($images); 
Then  I got 
 string(100) "select * from `image_gallery` where (`type` = ? and `wc` = ? and `fc` = ? and `yc` = ? and `sc` = ?)"  
I selected all value but why I got this query?

Comment: Change $images->count()  to $images->first() in blade.

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra I changed. now I got this error Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Call to a member function first() on string.   And query also same string(100) "select * from `image_gallery` where (`type` = ? and `wc` = ? and `fc` = ? and `yc` = ? and `sc` = ?)"

Comment: You are not getting eloquent collection as a result. You are getting results as a string. Can you check what you get $images? Please use this in your controller: dd($images);

Comment: And check the output.

Comment: I replaced as  dd($images); and here is what I got  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1307 ▼  #items: [] }  It seems like empty...

Comment: Yes, you don't have any records in your collection. Can you tell me the exact query you want to make for the search?

Comment: I already stored many photo data at my DB those are have info. And I would like to make query like this
If  user select 'type' column as w.  and 'wc' column as "N1" and 'fc' column as "f03"
ImageGallery::where('type', "w" and 'wc', "N1" and 'fc', "f03")->get();

Comment: User can select just one column.
For example  if User select  'type' column as w.
Query will be this ImageGallery::where('type', "w")->get();

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra Don't you have any idea my question's cause? I do really apreciate your help. Do you have more idea to fix this problem? Or should I close this question?

Comment: Dear @Ankur Mishra Thank you very much for keep helping me. your code helps me alot. I think I might ask this as another post. I really apreciate.

Comment: @greeniron Check the new answer that I have given. I am really sorry to respond to you very late. Sorry, dear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change something. Because your `$data` is an array. But you have declare as an object. For this reason you get this error.

```
$data = $request->all();

$images = ImageGallery::where(['type'=>$data['type']],
    ['wc'=>$data['type']],
    ['fc'=>$data['fc']],
    ['yc'=>$data['yc']],
    ['sc'=>$data['sc']])->get();
```

Comment: Dear @A.A Noman Thank you very much for helping me. I replace my code but I got same error...